# How to export query result to a text files with multiple records on it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I'm trying to export certain fields from the query below to a Text file. The problem I'm facing is that only one record is showing up in the text file when I export it, I also want to append none query results to this text file.

Also, some of the lines don't need to be repeated,

```
    odbccon.Open();
    OdbcCommand getcartons = new OdbcCommand("select * from wm242basd.chcart00 where chldno = '0010585567'", odbccon);
    OdbcDataAdapter adp = new OdbcDataAdapter(getcartons);
    OdbcDataReader odbcr = getcartons.ExecuteReader();
    while (odbcr.Read())
    {
        cartonnumber = odbcr["chcasn"].ToString() + "                 ";
        storenumber = odbcr["chstor"].ToString() + "  ";
        weightlbs = odbcr["chacwt"].ToString();
    }

    #region


    //Assign values to each String for Header Record - Type "A"
    constantA = "A";
    fileidentifier = "ASN";
    clientidentifier = "1111";                      //Currently Pending on Call from Friday
    primaryscac = "1111";                           //Currently Pending on Call from Friday
    dcidentifier = "ONT";
    shipmentID = "0010585567 ";                     //This String could come from DataBase OR could be populated from TextBox by User
    masterBOL = "                              ";   //This String could come from DataBase 
    buildingID = "    ";                            //Currently Pending on Call from Friday

    //Create Header Record - Type "A"
    w.WriteLine(constantA + fileidentifier + clientidentifier + primaryscac + dcidentifier + shipmentID + masterBOL + buildingID);


    //Assign values to each String for Load Record - Type "T"
    constantT = "T";
    trailerclosedate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    trailerclosetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmm");
    trailernumber = "            ";                 //Pending on App Accessability OR could be populated from TextBox by user
    sealnumber = "          ";
    expectedarrivaldate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    expectedarrivaltime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3).ToString("HHmm");
    trailerserialnumber = "          ";
    carrier = "    ";

    //Create Load Record - Type "T"
    w.WriteLine(constantT + trailerclosedate + trailerclosetime + trailernumber + sealnumber + expectedarrivaldate + expectedarrivaltime + trailerserialnumber + carrier);


    //Assign values to each String for Store Record - Type "B"
    constantB = "B";
    deliverycarrierSCAC = "    ";
    clientroute = "         ";
    businesscode = "  ";
    //storenumber = "1001  ";       //This String should come from the DataBase
    clientbolnumber = "            ";
    terminalcode = "   ";
    deliverydays = "000";
    deliverystarttime = "    ";
    deliveryendtime = "    ";
    carrierpro = "            ";
    expecteddeliverydate = "        ";

    //Create Store Record - Type "B"
    w.WriteLine(constantB + deliverycarrierSCAC + clientroute + businesscode + storenumber + clientbolnumber + terminalcode + deliverydays + deliverystarttime + deliveryendtime + carrierpro + expecteddeliverydate);


    //Assign values to each String for Store Record - Type "C"        
    constantC = "C";
    //cartonnumber = "1002333323569                 ";    //This String should come from DataBase
    //weightlbs = "0000000";                              //This String could also come from DataBase
    cubicfeet = "0000000";
    conveyable = "Y";
    specialhandling = "               ";
    cartonvalue = "00000000";
    cartonretail = "00000000";
    units = "0000";                                     //This String could also come from DataBase
    palletnumber = "                             ";     //This String could also come from DataBase

    //Create Store Record - Type "C"
    w.WriteLine(constantC + cartonnumber + weightlbs + cubicfeet + conveyable + specialhandling + cartonvalue + cartonretail + units + palletnumber);


    //Assign values to each String for Store Record - Type "D"
    constantD = "D";
    totalstorecartons = "0000023";                      //This String should come from DataBase
    totalstoreweight = "000000000";                     //This String could come from DataBase
    totalstorecubicfeet = "000000000";

    //Create Store Record - Type "D"
    w.WriteLine(constantD + totalstorecartons + totalstoreweight + totalstorecubicfeet);


    //Assign values to each String for Store Record - Type "E"
    constantE = "E";
    totaltrailercartons = "0000023";                    //This String should come from DataBase
    totaltrailerweight = "000000000";                   //This String could come from DataBase
    totaltrailercubicfeet = "000000000";

    //Create Store Record - Type "E"
    w.WriteLine(constantE + totaltrailercartons + totaltrailerweight + totaltrailercubicfeet);
    #endregion

    //Maintenance and Close
    w.Flush();
    w.Close();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your while loop is setting the three variables repeatedly, but once the loop is done, each variable only has one value.

thus, the values from the last record, and only those values, are used when writing to the file.

move the end brace of the while loop so it includes all code that you wish to be executed for each data record, but make sure that the file is opened before and closed after the while loop

Comment: Is it possible to exclude certain code inside the brace from repeating for every record?

Comment: certainly... any code that does not need to be performed for each record can be moved outside the while loop

Comment: what about if I need that code inside the brace but I don't want it to repeat, is this possible? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: for code to be executed inside the brace but not repeated, just surround the code with an if statement based on the condition under which it should be run.  For example, if it's something that should only be run once, add -->bool runOnce = true;<-- before the while loop, and then add -->if(runOnce) { runOnce = false; // then do whatever }<-- inside the loop